# Error in OpenGL Redbook example, Chapter 3

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I read the OpenGL Readbook 8th Editor. But I can't create example from Chapter 3 "Drawing Commands Example". Authors used in the example the own library `vmath.h`. But It don't work. They forgot add to library function "`vmath::translation(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat);`", although used it. And authors used the own library "`vapp.h`", which confuses me. There a lot of macros, by means which defined class. I'm really confused.
I used instead of their library, the "Eigen" library for linear algebra.
[Here is my code on GitHub](https://github.com/Nawy/cpp_example/blob/master/drawing_commands)
I compiled and run this program. It work. But I see a black window, but I should to see  a four triangles. What Did I do wrong?
P.S. I redid Authors's program, by means of used for matrices and vertices the "Eigen Library". I saw only the black screen. Why?! [Here is code on GitHub](https://github.com/Nawy/cpp_example/blob/master/author_drawing_command) 
I have two shaders:
vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;

out vec4 vs_fs_color;

void main(void)
{
    vs_fs_color = color;
    gl_Position = projection_matrix * (model_matrix * position);
}
```

And fragment shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec4 vs_fs_color;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    color = vs_fs_color;
}
```

I exactly use a these shaders.
[Here is what I should see.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B--XHc4ZdvdUVXZxY05oLURUTFk/edit?usp=sharing)
[This is original project(MSVC++)](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B--XHc4ZdvdUTHFseFdLdkF4RkE&usp=sharing)
[This is a include files(including `vapp.h` and `vapp.h`)](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B--XHc4ZdvdUWHdLR1lVd3hvNWM&usp=sharing)

Comment: Appears to be a mistake. Function is `translate`, not `translation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're setting up your `model_matrix`, the second argument to `glUniformMatrix4fv` should be 1, not 4. Also, you are using wrong indices in `frustum`. Change `result(2, 0)` to `result(0, 2)` and do the same for all the other pairs.